# seesaw macros not working with chrome

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With Chrome Version 30.0.1599.66 (the current), the seesaw macros at http://wiki.ros.org/seesawexample don't seem to work.  Specifically, if I click on "Bash" then on "Compiled" nothing is shown.  Confused me for a while before I tried Firefox, where this works logically.

Actually, I noticed this while trying to follow http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/TurtleBot%20Bringup, where I couldn't see/find the Deb Installiation Instructions, but the example also doesn't work for me.

ps. sorry for the broken links, answers.ros.org says I need more karma to publish links :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89606/seesaw-macros-not-working-with-chrome/) by [KevinNickels](https://answers.ros.org/users/6631/kevinnickels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-10-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-10**:
I fixed the links for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've ticketed it here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/75

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0